# Adding 'LI' Element before the last LI tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

After clicking on "Add Comment" button, I want `<li> </li>` to be added at the end but before the last `<li>`.

See the code:

```
<div class="newsComment">
  <ul class="CommentReplies">
     <li class="Heading">
       <h3> Comments </h3>
     </li>
      <li class="CommentRow"> Comment 1 </li>
      <li class="CommentRow"> Comment 2 </li>
      // ADD LI HERE WHEN CLICKING ON THE BUTTON
     <li class="CommentRow">
      <form id="FormAddComment">
       <input name="comment" type="text" />
       <input id="submit_AddNewsComment" type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
       </form>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>


$("#FormAddComment").submit(function() {
    data =  $(this).serialize();
    //Add LI
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the form is inside the `li`, use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find it, then [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before) to insert in front of it.

```
$("#FormAddComment").submit(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    data =  $this.serialize();

    //Add LI
    $this.closest("li").before(
        "<li>New content</li"
    );

    return false;
});
```

Comment: wouldn't `insertBefore` be the other way around? ie. `$('<li />').insertBefore($(this));`?

Comment: @David: Thank you, yes, fixed. Easily half the time, I'll get that wrongly, not least because the API is just plain worded wrong. In English, you say "insert this before that" so clearly the this is on the left and the that is on the right. :-)

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder.  $this should be $(this).   Also </li should be </li>

Comment: Sorry, Now I understand why you got $this - I thought it was typo!

Answer (score 3):

`$(this).closest('.CommentRow').before($('<li />'));` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `$("#FormAddComment")` submit function this will insert the `<li>`

```
$(this).closest('.CommentReplies').find('li:last').prepend('<li>Comment 3</li>');
```